# GWT example MVP app

Tags: gwt, mvp

I have been looking at this tutorial
https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/articles/mvp-architecture
What I was wondered is with this MVP style how efficient is it that every time a user changes page that it goes and creates a new instance of the Presenter.  Would the presenters be better if they were singletons?  My end goal is to deploy an app using PhoneGap so any performance gains would be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends on your implementation.

If you want the state to be saved on your view you could go with a singleton presenter/view.

It is more efficient, as you do not need to re init the view but less efficient if some transaction on another view makes a change that will need to change the first view. In this case you need to raise an event in the second presenter that is caught on the first presenter and modifies the view accordingly. This makes the application a little less predictable.

So if each presenter/view is independent a single view/presenter would be the thing to do.

In any other case I would go with a new presenter/view to re-initialize the data in the forms the view uses.

Bear in mind though that each new presenter that uses application wide variables (such as an event bus) would not be destroyed (garbage-collected) which would lead to the following problem:

Any time you load a View and an event is raised that is caught in the corresponding presenter, the event and all the calculations will occur as many times as a new presenter/view is generated.

Example:
-Presenter1/View1 is loaded and catches some event
-Presenter2/View2 is loaded
-Presenter1(new instance)/View1(new instance) is loaded and catches some event.
-Event is raised via the global event bus
-Presenter1 catches the event
-Presenter1(new instance) catches the event

So in essence (that is not a rule) a new presenter gives the GWT application a web-page with full postback feeling, and in the other case you have the Desktop application feeling that loads already existing forms.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sounds like I should leave it as is.  Do you think when throwing an Event to change page that the Event object itself should contain all the data from the page which triggered the event that I am interested in passing to the next page?

Comment: Implementing a client side database (basically a class that holds and caches your data) would help with sharing data across presenters and views. http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwDataGrid has an example of a ContactsDatabase class.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Singletons...yuck!

You don't have to create a new instance each time if you're lazily initializing presenters, and saving their reference for reuse.

Take a look at the following example that I took and modified from https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/articles/mvp-architecture-2#code_splitting to highlight how to reuse a presenter, similar to how you reuse views.

```
 public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent<String> event) {
    String token = event.getValue();

    if (token != null) {
      if (token.equals("list")) {
        GWT.runAsync(new RunAsyncCallback() {
          ...
          public void onSuccess() {
            // lazily initialize our views and presenters, and keep them around to be reused
            if (contactsView == null) {
              contactsView = new ContactsViewImpl<ContactDetails>();
            }
            if (contactsPresenter == null) {
              contactsPresenter = new ContactsPresenter(rpcService, eventBus, contactsView);
            }
            contactsPresenter.go(container);
          }
        });
      }
      ...
   }
```

Besides the performance advantage of code splitting via RunAsyncCallback, essentially, you keep reference to each Presenter as a AppController class field and reuse them when you switch history tokens.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use [gwt-platform](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-platform/). I used it in several projects and never had any performance issues with it. It's very powerful and helps you to structure your application in way to extend it more easily in the future while maintaining good performance.